# Write a script to identify max number of concurrent ajax calls allowed by browser for a particular domain

Tags: javascript, ajax

Is there any JavaScript to get number of concurrent Ajax calls allowed by browser for a particular domain.

Answer (score 1):

No. If you think you might hit the limit, consider using random subdomains to avoid hitting it.

Answer (score 0):

No. However there are sites such as [browserscope](http://www.browserscope.org/?category=network) which has the information you're looking for which means you can simply pass browser limitations as a json object and identify the client browser to use the limitations in your script.